# julia on windows 11 doesn't deserialize julia serilized file on windows 10

Tags: windows, julia

Julia on windows 11 doesn't deserialize julia serilized file on windows 10.
The file creadted on Julia about 1.7.3 and it's right file.
But if I try deserialize the file on Julia v1.8.5, it made an error.

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: array must be non-empty
Stacktrace:
  [1] pop!
    @ .\array.jl:1314 [inlined]
  [2] deserialize_cycle
  [6] handle_deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream}, b::Int32)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\adjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:919
  [7] deserialize
    @ C:\Users\adjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:813 [inlined]
  [8] deserialize(s::IOStream)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\adjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:800
  [9] open(f::typeof(deserialize), args::String; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Base .\io.jl:384
 [10] open
    @ .\io.jl:381 [inlined]
 [11] deserialize(filename::String)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\adjun\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:810
 [12] top-level scope
    @ d:\OneDrive\catO\다섯\AD 고 2 참\ori_4.jl:1522
```

Comment: I use  [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl) (which under the hood uses the HDF5 format)

Comment: or consider `using BSON` which is another great Julia package for long term object serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/#Serialization.serialize

> In some cases, the word size (32- or 64-bit) of the reading and writing machines must match. In rarer cases the OS or architecture must also match, for example when using packages that contain platform-dependent code.